# Emailing the results of a series of checkboxes from a contact form

Tags: php, string, email, checkbox, foreach

I've been at this for days now- surely it shouldn't be this difficult!

I'm making a script to send the details of a form to my email address once the form's sent. This has never been an issue until now as I've never needed to use checkboxes in a form before. Excuse any dodgy terminology as I'm still trying to learn the basics of php!

I've managed to get the array to pull as an echo on the 'thanks for filling in the form' page, where the php script is stored (I don't want it there, but at least I know I'm on the right track!) but what I really need is for the various boxes that were checked on the form to be sent to my email.

example html from form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="features_wanted[]" id="about_me" value="about_me" />
<input type="checkbox" name="features_wanted[]" id="showcase" value="showcase" />
<input type="checkbox" name="features_wanted[]" id="resource" value="resource" />
```

Example of the php echo that's working fine:

```
$features_wanted = $_POST['features_wanted'] ;
foreach($features_wanted as $feature) echo "$feature<br />";
```

Where do I go now?! I've built my message and it's being received fine. Here's an example of some of the script. The variables are being pulled and are working fine for all of the bits of the string:

```
$message = 
"name: $first_name $surname\n" .
"email_address: $email_address\n" .
"mobile number: $mobile\n" .
"address:\t $address1\n" .
"\t\t $address2\n" .
"\t\t $city\n" .
"\t\t $postcode\n" ;
```

The email is sent like this and is also working fine:

```
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From:' . $email_address) ;
```

So I want to work the foreach (or something else that'll do the job- implode, maybe?) into the $message string. It's plain text, not HTML, so echo's not appropriate, I don't think.

Shouldn't this be something that's really easy, since a lot of forms must include multiple choice checkboxes? There's surprisingly little useful info on the internet that I can find, and I've been looking since Friday!

I hope that all makes sense...!

Thanks in advance for any help anyone's able to provide,

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would handle it:

```
$message .= "Features Wanted: \n";
foreach($_POST['features_wanted'] as $value){
    $message .= $value . "\n";
}
```

Although using `implode()` would also be an option

```
$message .= implode(" ", $_POST['features_wanted']);
```

I'm not sure which would actually be faster though.

Comment: I used the second method and it's adding the features to the end of the email! Thanks! How would I add the 'features wanted:  x y z' into the body of the email? The .= concatenates the strings, rather than integrating the various 'features' into the message.

Comment: maybe if i break $message down into separate variables... but wouldn't that be a bit messy?

Comment: Hello again JRSofty.

I've done this:
$features = "features wanted: " ;
$features .= implode(" ,", $_POST['features_wanted']);

And then added the the souped-up $features variable into the $message string. Works a charm!

Thanks VERY much for your help!

Martin.